# Convert hsl to hsv color codes and vice versa in Python

Tags: python, colors, hsv, hsl

I'm currently trying to convert hsl color codes to hsv and vice versa in Python, but can't find an easy way to do this.

I tried converting the codes indirectly by converting hsl to rgb and rgb to hsv using the `colorsys` package. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for some reason. I always get incredibly small values (`< 0`, so that doesn't make any sense).

Here's what I did:

```
import colorsys

def hsv_to_hsl(hsv):
    h, s, v = hsv
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
    r, g, b = rgb
    hls = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
    return hls

hsv = (300, 65, 40)

print(hsv)
print(hsv_to_hsl(hsv))
```

I also tried writing my own function based on a JavaScript function I found on GitHub, but I get the same weird values there (see code for converting hsv to hsl below). The problem is I don't really get the formula on Wikipedia, so to be honest I don't even know if what I computed below makes any sense.

```
import math

def hsv_to_hsl(hsv):
    h, sat, val = hsv
    
    # hue h stays the same
    
    # saturation s
    if (2-sat)*val < 1:
        s = sat*val / ((2-sat)*val)
    else: s = sat*val / (2-(2-sat)*val)

    # lightness l
    l = 2-sat * val/2 
    
    # return code as tuple
    return (h, s, l)
```

Is there an easy way to do this using a package or do you have an idea of what I could do differently in my function?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Interconversion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure to normalize the values according to the matching ranges. According to your values (and the range hints in [this website](http://colormine.org/convert/hsl-to-hsv)), it seems you're using values of H in the range `[0, 360]` ; S and V in the range `[0, 100]`. On the other hand, the built-in library [`colorsys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html) uses all `[0, 1]` ranges. So a bit of normalization will give you the required results:

```
import colorsys

def hsv_to_hsl(hsv):
    h, s, v = hsv
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h/360, s/100, v/100)
    r, g, b = rgb
    h, l, s = colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
    return h*360, s*100, l*100

hsv = (300, 65, 40)

print(hsv)
print(hsv_to_hsl(hsv))
```

Now gives the expected:

```
(300, 65, 40)
(300.0, 48.148148148148145, 27.0)
```

---

If you are looking for a manual implementation, you can use the algorithm described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Interconversion) (now the values are: H in range `[0, 360]` and S,V and L are in `[0, 1]`):

```py
def hsv_to_hsl(hsv):
    h, s, v = hsv
    l = v * (1 - s/2)
    s = 0 if l in (0, 1) else (v - l)/min(l, 1-l)
    return h, s, l

def hsl_to_hsv(hsl):
    h, s, l = hsl
    v = l + s * min(l, 1-l)
    s = 0 if v == 0 else 2*(1 - l/v)
    return h, s, v
```

To compare the result with `colorsys`:

```
h, s, l = (300, 48.148, 27)

custom = hsl_to_hsv((h, s/100, l/100))
print("Custom function: ", custom[0], custom[1]*100, custom[2]*100)
expected = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h/360, l/100, s/100))
print("Expected result: ", expected[0]*360, expected[1]*100, expected[2]*100)
```

Indeed gives:

```
Custom function:  300 64.99986499986498 39.99996
Expected result:  300.0 64.999864999865 39.99996
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a native Python coder so this is pretty simplistic, but is based on the [formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Interconversion) and returns accurate values according to [colorizer.org](http://colorizer.org/):

```py
def hsl_to_hsv(hsl):
    hue,sat,lum = hsl
    if hue < 0 or hue > 360 or sat < 0 or sat > 1 or lum < 0 or lum > 1:
        exit

    h = hue
    v = lum + sat * min(lum, 1 - lum)
    if v == 0:
        s = 0
    else:
        s = 2 * (1 - lum / v)

    return h,s,v

def hsv_to_hsl(hsv):
    hue,sat,val = hsv
    if hue < 0 or hue > 360 or sat < 0 or sat > 1 or val < 0 or val > 1:
        exit

    h = hue
    l = val * (1 - sat / 2)
    if l == 0 or l == 1:
        s = 0
    else:
        s = (val - l) / min(l, 1 - l)

    return h,s,l

print (hsl_to_hsv((36.9,0.5118,0.751)))
print (hsv_to_hsl((36.9,0.2902,0.8784)))
```

Output:

```
(36.9, 0.29014721809684496, 0.8784382)
(36.9, 0.5117560784762163, 0.75094416)
```

Note that hue is a float with values 0 to 360, the other values are floats with values from 0 to 1, often expressed as percentages. Your problem using the `colorsys` library may have been that you were passing larger values like `29` instead of `0.29`.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out the `colorsys` module:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/colorsys.html

Examples from the site:

```
colorsys.rgb_to_yiq(r, g, b)
#Convert the color from RGB coordinates to YIQ coordinates.

colorsys.yiq_to_rgb(y, i, q)
#Convert the color from YIQ coordinates to RGB coordinates.

colorsys.rgb_to_hls(r, g, b)
#Convert the color from RGB coordinates to HLS coordinates.

colorsys.hls_to_rgb(h, l, s)
#Convert the color from HLS coordinates to RGB coordinates.

colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)
#Convert the color from RGB coordinates to HSV coordinates.

colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h, s, v)
#Convert the color from HSV coordinates to RGB coordinates.
```

From this, you can convert hls -> rgb -> hsv

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! As I mentioned above, I already tried this (in fact my first approach), but it doesn't work. For some reason, this produces negative values.